# Is it possible to pass an argument to a Svelte component that specifies a particular file to import?

Tags: import, svelte-3

I'm building a photography site. The user can click on links to various photo album components, e.g. an album of black and white portraits, an album of black and white architecture, etc.

The displayed contents (i.e., image file paths and corresponding image captions) for each album are detailed in a json file that is imported at the top of the album component, e.g. `import {images} from './albums/bwportraits.js';`, `import {images} from './album/bwarchitecture.js';`, etc.

Apart from the album-specific imports, the rest of each album component is identical. I would like a generic `<Album />` component but be able to pass the json file to import as a prop, i.e. `<Album album = "bwportraits" />`, `<Album album = "bwarchitecture" />` and the import within the `<Album />` to be something equivalent to (the non-valid) `import {images} from './albums/{album}';`.

That is, I would like to dynamically specify which file to import. This does not appear possible - or, at least, I do not know how to do this.

It would, of course, be possible to import every album json file into the `<Album />` component; they are reasonably small and the performance hit would be negligible. But this feels a little unclean to me. Is there a 'cleaner' workaround that anyone can suggest?

Comment: Why not using a database instead of json files?

Comment: Not sure how this would solve/change the problem.

Comment: You don't need to import any file dynamically, you just use the parameter to query the database for the needed data.

Comment: I don't particularly want to use a database. So far, importing all json album specification files and passing the one required at a time to the receiving component doesn't seem to have a performance hit. If and when it does, I'll consider using a database. Thanks.